# Outdated MySQL WorkBench packages are buggy, upgrade is disallowed

Tags: upgrade, versions, mysql-workbench

I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop.
Due to dependencies, not many MySQL WorkBench versions are available for use. Hence, I am more or less forced to use 6.3.6 which suffers from a bug when exporting a DB. (Exception => Can't export DB as not root user.)
The bug is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521822/mysql-workbench-error-1142-error-querying-security-information-on-data-export).

There is available WorkBench 6.3.7 for download for Linux Ubuntu 16.04, but I just can't use it. Is there any chance to use this 6.3.7 in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

I mean, wouldn't it be great if Canonical elevated version of the pretty outdated workbench v.6.0.8 in their Software Center offer ?

These are my dependency errors, that prevent me to install 6.3.7

```
peter@peter-LIFEBOOK-S6420:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-1ubu1604-amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 224508 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-1ubu1604-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (6.3.7-1ubu1604) over (6.3.7-1ubu1604) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Version of libcairo2:amd64 on system is 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1.1.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libcairomm-1.0-1v5 (>= 1.12.0); however:
  Package libcairomm-1.0-1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.46.0); however:
  Package libglibmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libncurses5 (>= 6); however:
  Version of libncurses5:amd64 on system is 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1); however:
  Version of libodbc1:amd64 on system is 2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpangomm-1.4-
dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
^Cdpkg: error processing package shared-mime-info (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
 shared-mime-info
```

I would even try to install them one by one, but actually got nowhere..

Comment: Not an answer but there is also [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/).

Comment: "I mean, wouldn't it be great if Canonical elevated version of the pretty outdated workbench v.6.0.8 in their Software Center offer ?" No. "but I just can't use it" Oh? Care to share why not? As this stands I don't  see anyone answering your =problem= of not being able to install 6.3.6

Comment: @Rinzwind
Let me quote you and myself:
R: Oh? Care to share why not?"
P: "Due to dependencies, I am forced to use MySQL WorkBench 6.3.6 ..."

R: "your =problem= of not being able to install 6.3.6"
P: You are wrong. I did install and run WB 6.3.6  BUT ITS BUGGY as the link suggests. And I can't install 6.3.7 on 14.04 DUE TO insufficient DEPENDENCES :)

Care to share why it wouldn't be great if Canonical'd upgrade its outdated software center packages ?

Comment: @Rinzwind 
Why is is that as soon as there is anything that might sound just a tiny bit like a complain about Canonical, immediately someone too wise raises making pple with less reputation a complete dull, however with better reading of the original post ... ehm...

Comment: @DBeaver 
Thanx that would help, in case I will have to relinquish from using WB 6.3.7 @ 14.04
I can allways use 6.3.4 which is available and does NOT exhibit that bug.

Comment: Well a downloaded WB 6.3.4 won't install either - due to same problem as 6.3.7 - dependencies.
My choice is community which is (6.3.6-1ubu1404) over (6.3.4-1ubu1410)
and the very much outdated 6.0.8 from Software Center.
Anyone with experiences on other Linux distros: Which distro could I go for in order to get better SW package support ?

Comment: @Peter Can you include the exact dependency errors it says when you try and install the package from MySQL?  Because I have the latest version on 14.04 without issues, and it seems to work without problems.

Comment: @Thomas 
Yep, sure - done.

Comment: @Peter did you do `sudo apt-get install -f` after that?  That tells `apt`/`apt-get` to try and resolve the dependencies by installing them.  (`dpkg` isn't really smart like that, and doesn't resolve the dependencies and try and actually install such dependencies).

Comment: @Thomas 
Thanx for the hint. I did it now as you suggest. It did look promising first, had installed some packages (other than those missing), un-installed my community 6.3.6 (I went back to it in the meantime), but actually after retry to install 6.3.7 - the result is same.

Comment: @Peter The core issue is you're installing a 16.04 package on 14.04.  I just checked an email account where I track things, it seems like MySQL workbench isn't supported pre-16.04 anymore.  That must be a recent change...

Comment: @Thomas 
Yap - I know 6.3.7 is targeted for 16.04
But still I need that update cause 6.3.6 has that bug. Therefore I asked this question to make it run on my 14.04
You mentioned it worked for you somehow ;)

Comment: @Peter You're right, but I think I may have forgotten that I have a Xenial chroot where it runs... very painfully I might add, but it 'runs'.  Side effect of getting no sleep.

Comment: @Peter " Care to share why it wouldn't be great if Canonical'd upgrade its outdated software center packages ?" That would violate 1 core rule of Ubuntu. Ubuntu is about stable software. And stable means the version it was during the feature freeze of Ubuntu. "But still I need that update cause 6.3.6 has that bug" No, you do not. 6.3.4 does not have that bug (as noted in the bug report).

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you for sharing the info. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It looks like MySQL isn't supporting anything before Xenial anymore](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,646892,646892#msg-646892) for MySQL workbench, which suggests it might not be possible to make it work on just 14.04.  (Yet another reason to upgrade...)

In my comments above, I neglected to take into account I have a Xenial chroot on my computer, which is where some things run from (like MySQL workbench, albeit not as kindly as I'd like it to).  Because of this, I forgot that I don't have a 'pure' 14.04 install.  Given this, however, I believe it's not possible to get the latest "generally available" prebuilt binaries.

There is a source code tarball available from MySQL, you may wish to download and compile MySQL workbench latest from source to see if that works, but I can't provide any guarantees it'll work.

Comment: That is exactly what I was afraid of..
I even tried to export my DB using provided 6.0.8 and it ain't work either ! Not an exception though, but the process hangs and never ends. DB is no bigger than 10 MB
Now I get really upset about Oracle open source SW  :) 
Perhaps they just try to give us another reason to buy the real SW :)

Comment: @Peter I would consider using mysqldump instead, rather than the GUI, to get the DB dump.  It should work, while Workbench might not.

Comment: Thanx, I'd also go for Jos' suggested  DBeaver alternative do WBench.